# Did the mathematician Garrett Birkhoff ever work with or mention Feynman's path integrals?

Tags: mathematics, physics, mathematicians, quantum-mechanics

Did Garrett Birkhoff ever work with Feynman's path integral? Did he ever work in his Many-Histories interpretation? Or at least, did he mention it in any of his articles?

Comment: Why do you think he might have?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Garrett Birkhoff was my Ph.D. advisor.  A MathSciNet search shows that there is no paper by Birkhoff where the word "Feynman" is mentioned in the review.  Birkhoff has a 1935 paper about infinite-dimensional integrals, but that was before Feynman's integral.